# Must Declare Scalar variable @nRuleId

Tags: sql-server

```
USE GDMDBNS_1720
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
        AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'usp_RmsExecuteValidationRule')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_RmsExecuteValidationRule
END
GO

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RmsExecuteValidationRule]
     @nRuleId INT,
     @FIPSName VARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @strRuleQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @sqlstat AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @params  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @strRuleQuery = N'SELECT RULE_QUERY from GdmValidationRuleMaster where
    RULE_ID = @nRuleId'

    SET @sqlstat = @strRuleQuery

    SET @params = N'@FIPSName VARCHAR(5)'
    EXEC sp_executesql @params,
        @query = @sqlstat,
        @FIPSName = @FIPSName

END
```

got error while Debugging  must declare scalar variable @nRuleId . I have already declared. But error is pooping out always.

Comment: you havent assigned a value to `@nRuleId`

Comment: `sp_executesql `wants an sql statement as first parameter, params comes second, your `@strRuleQuery` contans an variable `@nRuleId`which is not declared as parmeter and not assigned but you declare a paramter `@FIPSName`which is assigned but not needed

Comment: Have you checked any of the answers given?

Answer (score 0):

You must rewrite execution part:

```
SET @params = N'@FIPSName VARCHAR(5), @nRuleId int'
EXEC sp_executesql  @strRuleQuery, @params, @FIPSName = @FIPSName, @nRuleId = @nRuleId
```

I don't understand, why do you pass `@FIPSName` as parameter, it is not used in your batch.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a number of issues with the code, as is.

To return a value, you need to declare an OUTPUT parameter and the variable @FIPSName is not actually used in the code, and @strRuleQuery is superfluous in this code.

Here is the code from inside the SProc, that should be closer to your needs.

```
-- Parameters
DECLARE
@nRuleId INT = 1,
 @FIPSName VARCHAR(5) = 'ITS'

-- Local variables
DECLARE @sqlstat AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @params  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @RULE_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sqlstat = N'SELECT @RULE_QUERY=RULE_QUERY from GdmValidationRuleMaster where RULE_ID = @nRuleId'

SET @params = N'@nRuleId INT, @RULE_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
EXEC sp_executesql 
    @sqlstat,
    @params,
    @nRuleId = @nRuleId, @RULE_QUERY= @RULE_QUERY OUTPUT

-- Output
SELECT @RULE_QUERY
```